# Disable secure connection for MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, qt, ssl, odbc

Ubuntu 22.04, Qt 6.2.0:

```
QSqlDatabase _db;

bool OdbcSql::connectToDB(QUrl host, QString database, QString username, QString password)
{
    _db.setDatabaseName(QStringLiteral("Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.0.so.1.1; Server=%1;Database=%2").arg(host.url()).arg(database));
    _db.setUserName(username);
    _db.setPassword(password);
    _db.setConnectOptions("SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=5;SQL_ATTR_LOGIN_TIMEOUT=5");

    bool ret = _db.open();
    if (!ret) _db.lastError();
    return ret;
}
```

> QSqlError("", "QODBC: Unable to connect", "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed:EE certificate key too weak] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection")

The server is not under my control.
Because it's an internal connection between two machines inside a LAN, can I disable the SSL requirement for the ODBC connection in order to fix this issue?

Is there any other way to fix it?

Comment: Which server is it you don't control (the SQL Server or the Ubuntu machine)? As per [ODBC Driver 18.0 for SQL Server Released](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/odbc-driver-18-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3169228) one of the breaking changes was the default setting of `Encrypt=False/No;` changing to `Encrypt=True/Yes;`. You could change it back to `Encrypt=False/No;` to disable connection encryption, which would send all of your SQL Server queries and results over the network "in the clear", but you should probably figure out what's the issue with the SQL Server cert.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning sorry for the missing information: the Windows machine where the SQL Server runs. I don't understand where I have to change the `Encrypt` flag. In which file is it stored?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `QSqlDatabase` class but based on your code I expect it can be included in the parameter passed in to `setDatabaseName`. It could be either `Encrypt=False;` or `Encrypt=No;` depending on what translation is happening inside `QSqlDatabase`.

Comment: Aside... also curious how you managed to install ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server on Ubuntu 22.04 since it's not available via [https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.04/prod.list](https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.04/prod.list) yet.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning https://askubuntu.com/a/1409311/1036006

Comment: It works using `sqlsrv_*` methods, not PDO (at least I'm not able to work with it)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning that should be an answer rather than a comment. By the way the accepted parameter was `Encrypt=No;`